# Адаптивная версия одной страницы

Tags: html, css, html5

У меня возникло желание адаптировать данную экспозицию (
https://munister-v.github.io/me.html) под мобильные устройства. На данный момент я добился корректного отображения страницы, однако сама ее верстка (тип верстки), как мне понимается, не предназначен для адаптива. Можно убрать картинку, но тогда и сам плывет. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно для этого нужно иметь какой-то аккуратный джаваскрипт, который как бы убирает пустую нижнюю часть (я новичок, поэтому прошу прощения за лексику)

[image: Как сделать адаптивным страницу]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"NRJS-c685010af489d443818","applicationID":"405834861","transactionName":"clYMQEAKCg1dQBxEBl9KTVJHCQoRWVVWGxBZVhU=","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":275,"agent":""}</script>
<script>(window.NREUM||(NREUM={})).loader_config={licenseKey:"NRJS-c685010af489d443818",applicationID:"405834861"};window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(e,t,n){function r(n){if(!t[n]){var i=t[n]={exports:{}};e[n][0].call(i.exports,function(t){var i=e[n][1][t];return r(i||t)},i,i.exports)}return t[n].exports}if("function"==typeof __nr_require)return __nr_require;for(var i=0;i<n.length;i++)r(n[i]);return r}({1:[function(e,t,n){function r(){}function i(e,t,n){return function(){return o(e,[u.now()].concat(c(arguments)),t?null:this,n),t?void 0:this}}var o=e("handle"),a=e(6),c=e(7),f=e("ee").get("tracer"),u=e("loader"),s=NREUM;"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=s);var d=["setPageViewName","setCustomAttribute","setErrorHandler","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","addRelease"],p="api-",l=p+"ixn-";a(d,function(e,t){s[t]=i(p+t,!0,"api")}),s.addPageAction=i(p+"addPageAction",!0),s.setCurrentRouteName=i(p+"routeName",!0),t.exports=newrelic,s.interaction=function(){return(new r).get()};var m=r.prototype={createTracer:function(e,t){var n={},r=this,i="function"==typeof t;return o(l+"tracer",[u.now(),e,n],r),function(){if(f.emit((i?"":"no-")+"fn-start",[u.now(),r,i],n),i)try{return t.apply(this,arguments)}catch(e){throw f.emit("fn-err",[arguments,this,e],n),e}finally{f.emit("fn-end",[u.now()],n)}}}};a("actionText,setName,setAttribute,save,ignore,onEnd,getContext,end,get".split(","),function(e,t){m[t]=i(l+t)}),newrelic.noticeError=function(e,t){"string"==typeof e&&(e=new Error(e)),o("err",[e,u.now(),!1,t])}},{}],2:[function(e,t,n){function r(){return c.exists&&performance.now?Math.round(performance.now()):(o=Math.max((new Date).getTime(),o))-a}function i(){return o}var o=(new Date).getTime(),a=o,c=e(8);t.exports=r,t.exports.offset=a,t.exports.getLastTimestamp=i},{}],3:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t){var n=e.getEntries();n.forEach(function(e){"first-paint"===e.name?d("timing",["fp",Math.floor(e.startTime)]):"first-contentful-paint"===e.name&&d("timing",["fcp",Math.floor(e.startTime)])})}function i(e,t){var n=e.getEntries();n.length>0&&d("lcp",[n[n.length-1]])}function o(e){e.getEntries().forEach(function(e){e.hadRecentInput||d("cls",[e])})}function a(e){if(e instanceof m&&!g){var t=Math.round(e.timeStamp),n={type:e.type};t<=p.now()?n.fid=p.now()-t:t>p.offset&&t<=Date.now()?(t-=p.offset,n.fid=p.now()-t):t=p.now(),g=!0,d("timing",["fi",t,n])}}function c(e){d("pageHide",[p.now(),e])}if(!("init"in NREUM&&"page_view_timing"in NREUM.init&&"enabled"in NREUM.init.page_view_timing&&NREUM.init.page_view_timing.enabled===!1)){var f,u,s,d=e("handle"),p=e("loader"),l=e(5),m=NREUM.o.EV;if("PerformanceObserver"in window&&"function"==typeof window.PerformanceObserver){f=new PerformanceObserver(r);try{f.observe({entryTypes:["paint"]})}catch(v){}u=new PerformanceObserver(i);try{u.observe({entryTypes:["largest-contentful-paint"]})}catch(v){}s=new PerformanceObserver(o);try{s.observe({type:"layout-shift",buffered:!0})}catch(v){}}if("addEventListener"in document){var g=!1,y=["click","keydown","mousedown","pointerdown","touchstart"];y.forEach(function(e){document.addEventListener(e,a,!1)})}l(c)}},{}],4:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t){if(!i)return!1;if(e!==i)return!1;if(!t)return!0;if(!o)return!1;for(var n=o.split("."),r=t.split("."),a=0;a<r.length;a++)if(r[a]!==n[a])return!1;return!0}var i=null,o=null,a=/Version\/(\S+)\s+Safari/;if(navigator.userAgent){var c=navigator.userAgent,f=c.match(a);f&&c.indexOf("Chrome")===-1&&c.indexOf("Chromium")===-1&&(i="Safari",o=f[1])}t.exports={agent:i,version:o,match:r}},{}],5:[function(e,t,n){function r(e){function t(){e(a&&document[a]?document[a]:document[i]?"hidden":"visible")}"addEventListener"in document&&o&&document.addEventListener(o,t,!1)}t.exports=r;var i,o,a;"undefined"!=typeof document.hidden?(i="hidden",o="visibilitychange",a="visibilityState"):"undefined"!=typeof document.msHidden?(i="msHidden",o="msvisibilitychange"):"undefined"!=typeof document.webkitHidden&&(i="webkitHidden",o="webkitvisibilitychange",a="webkitVisibilityState")},{}],6:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t){var n=[],r="",o=0;for(r in e)i.call(e,r)&&(n[o]=t(r,e[r]),o+=1);return n}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;t.exports=r},{}],7:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t,n){t||(t=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=e?e.length:0);for(var r=-1,i=n-t||0,o=Array(i<0?0:i);++r<i;)o[r]=e[t+r];return o}t.exports=r},{}],8:[function(e,t,n){t.exports={exists:"undefined"!=typeof window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&"undefined"!=typeof window.performance.timing.navigationStart}},{}],ee:[function(e,t,n){function r(){}function i(e){function t(e){return e&&e instanceof r?e:e?f(e,c,o):o()}function n(n,r,i,o){if(!p.aborted||o){e&&e(n,r,i);for(var a=t(i),c=v(n),f=c.length,u=0;u<f;u++)c[u].apply(a,r);var d=s[w[n]];return d&&d.push([b,n,r,a]),a}}function l(e,t){h[e]=v(e).concat(t)}function m(e,t){var n=h[e];if(n)for(var r=0;r<n.length;r++)n[r]===t&&n.splice(r,1)}function v(e){return h[e]||[]}function g(e){return d[e]=d[e]||i(n)}function y(e,t){u(e,function(e,n){t=t||"feature",w[n]=t,t in s||(s[t]=[])})}var h={},w={},b={on:l,addEventListener:l,removeEventListener:m,emit:n,get:g,listeners:v,context:t,buffer:y,abort:a,aborted:!1};return b}function o(){return new r}function a(){(s.api||s.feature)&&(p.aborted=!0,s=p.backlog={})}var c="nr@context",f=e("gos"),u=e(6),s={},d={},p=t.exports=i();p.backlog=s},{}],gos:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t,n){if(i.call(e,t))return e[t];var r=n();if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{return Object.defineProperty(e,t,{value:r,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),r}catch(o){}return e[t]=r,r}var i=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;t.exports=r},{}],handle:[function(e,t,n){function r(e,t,n,r){i.buffer([e],r),i.emit(e,t,n)}var i=e("ee").get("handle");t.exports=r,r.ee=i},{}],id:[function(e,t,n){function r(e){var t=typeof e;return!e||"object"!==t&&"function"!==t?-1:e===window?0:a(e,o,function(){return i++})}var i=1,o="nr@id",a=e("gos");t.exports=r},{}],loader:[function(e,t,n){function r(){if(!E++){var e=b.info=NREUM.info,t=p.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];if(setTimeout(u.abort,3e4),!(e&&e.licenseKey&&e.applicationID&&t))return u.abort();f(h,function(t,n){e[t]||(e[t]=n)});var n=a();c("mark",["onload",n+b.offset],null,"api"),c("timing",["load",n]);var r=p.createElement("script");r.src="https://"+e.agent,t.parentNode.insertBefore(r,t)}}function i(){"complete"===p.readyState&&o()}function o(){c("mark",["domContent",a()+b.offset],null,"api")}var a=e(2),c=e("handle"),f=e(6),u=e("ee"),s=e(4),d=window,p=d.document,l="addEventListener",m="attachEvent",v=d.XMLHttpRequest,g=v&&v.prototype;NREUM.o={ST:setTimeout,SI:d.setImmediate,CT:clearTimeout,XHR:v,REQ:d.Request,EV:d.Event,PR:d.Promise,MO:d.MutationObserver};var y=""+location,h={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-1184.min.js"},w=v&&g&&g[l]&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent),b=t.exports={offset:a.getLastTimestamp(),now:a,origin:y,features:{},xhrWrappable:w,userAgent:s};e(1),e(3),p[l]?(p[l]("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),d[l]("load",r,!1)):(p[m]("onreadystatechange",i),d[m]("onload",r)),c("mark",["firstbyte",a.getLastTimestamp()],null,"api");var E=0},{}],"wrap-function":[function(e,t,n){function r(e){return!(e&&e instanceof Function&&e.apply&&!e[a])}var i=e("ee"),o=e(7),a="nr@original",c=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,f=!1;t.exports=function(e,t){function n(e,t,n,i){function nrWrapper(){var r,a,c,f;try{a=this,r=o(arguments),c="function"==typeof n?n(r,a):n||{}}catch(u){p([u,"",[r,a,i],c])}s(t+"start",[r,a,i],c);try{return f=e.apply(a,r)}catch(d){throw s(t+"err",[r,a,d],c),d}finally{s(t+"end",[r,a,f],c)}}return r(e)?e:(t||(t=""),nrWrapper[a]=e,d(e,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}function u(e,t,i,o){i||(i="");var a,c,f,u="-"===i.charAt(0);for(f=0;f<t.length;f++)c=t[f],a=e[c],r(a)||(e[c]=n(a,u?c+i:i,o,c))}function s(n,r,i){if(!f||t){var o=f;f=!0;try{e.emit(n,r,i,t)}catch(a){p([a,n,r,i])}f=o}}function d(e,t){if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)try{var n=Object.keys(e);return n.forEach(function(n){Object.defineProperty(t,n,{get:function(){return e[n]},set:function(t){return e[n]=t,t}})}),t}catch(r){p([r])}for(var i in e)c.call(e,i)&&(t[i]=e[i]);return t}function p(t){try{e.emit("internal-error",t)}catch(n){}}return e||(e=i),n.inPlace=u,n.flag=a,n}},{}]},{},["loader"]);</script>
  
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" href="https://static.codepen.io/assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-5ae1a0698dcc2402e9712f7d01ed509a57814f994c660df9f7a952f3060705ee.png" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="CodePen">


<link rel="mask-icon" type=""https://github.githubassets.com/favicons/favicon.svg" color="#111" />


  <title>About me</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

  
  
<style>
@supports not (shape-outside: circle()) {
  body:before {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(35%, #64c8c8), color-stop(65%, #64c8c8), to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)));
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, #64c8c8 35%, #64c8c8 65%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    content: 'shape-outside is not supported in this browser';
    display: block;
    font-size: .825rem;
    left: 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.02rem;
    padding: .25rem 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
img {
  float: left;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  shape-outside: ellipse(224px 320px at 35.1% 50%);
}

body {
  background-color: #00001a;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Libre Baskerville", serif;
  line-height: 1.7;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

main,
.title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 60rem;
}

.title {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin: 0 0 .5rem 0;
  padding: 3.5rem 0 0;
}
.title span {
  color: #cfedfc;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin: 0;
}

@supports (shape-outside: circle()) {
  .title {
    padding: 2.0rem 0 0;
  }
}
.intro {
  color: #cc9966;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 1.15rem;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}

p {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
}

.first {
  padding-top: 1.22rem;
}
</style>

  <script>
  window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
</script>

  
  
  <script>
  if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
    window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
  }
</script>


</head>

<body translate="no" >
  <main>
    <img src="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/150150/yoga.png">  
    
    <p class="title">About me<span></span>
</p>
    
    <p class="intro">The following are a few of my favorite excerpts from the 2005 Stanford University commencement speech given by Steve Jobs.</p>
    
    <p class="first">“No one wants to die. Even people who want to go to heaven don't want to die to get there. And yet death is the destination we all share. No one has ever escaped it. And that is as it should be, because Death is very likely the single best invention of Life. It is Life's change agent. It clears out the old to make way for the new. Right now the new is you, but someday not too long from now, you will gradually become the old and be cleared away. Sorry to be so dramatic, but it is quite true.</p>

    <p>Your time is limited, so don't waste it living someone else's life. Don't be trapped by dogma — which is living with the results of other people's thinking. Don't let the noise of others' opinions drown out your own inner voice. And most important, have the courage to follow your heart and intuition. They somehow already know what you truly want to become. Everything else is secondary.</p>

    <p>Stay Hungry. Stay Foolish.”</p>  
    
</main>
  
  
  
  
  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Просто перенесите текст под картинку

Comment: Как это сделать? Взять медиа-запрос, а внутри его оформить грид одноколоночный?

Comment: проще флексами сделать: flex-direction: column ;) ну и медиа конечно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не добились адаптива. Вы добились того, что весь контент просто масштабируется в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Никакой чудо-javascript здесь не поможет. Пустое пространство внизу у Вас это свободное место на экране, куда его можно деть? Только если отпилить половину экрана)). В этом случае нужно использовать медиа-запросы. Например:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    p {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Этот код говорит о том, что при ширине экрана от 0 до 500px тег `p` должен быть шириной 100%. И таким образом нужно подгонять все элементы на странице в зависимости от разрешения экрана. Это и есть адаптив. А делать просто масштабирование это бессмысленно. Такая верстка не будет удобна для пользователей, да и поисковики такой адаптив не засчитают.

Comment: Спасибо, понял за адаптив. Попробывал медиа-запрос - параграфы 100% в адаптивном (до 500px) не формируют. Все также, как и раньше.

Comment: Про параграф это я образно написал. Если хотите увидеть результат, то пропишите картинке float:none;. А вообще если хотите сделать нормально поудаляйте все скрипты, не знаю чем Вы сделали эту масштабируемую верстку и переделайте все просто используя html, css и медиа-запросы.